# Antenna Tuner Range

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, antenna-tuner, kenwood

I have a Kenwood TS-480S and a Kenwood TS-870S both with built in antenna tuners. On the TS-870S I have a ZS6BKW multiband antenna and on the TS-480S I have a vertical whip with two counterpoise lines which gives me an SWR of around 1.4 ON 40m. It works but is noisy.

On the TS-870S the only band I get a good SWR is on 40m of 1.6. On the other bands the SWR is as high as 3.0 and 80m is 4.1. Now my question is this: How high can the SWR be before the antenna tuners will no longer tune?

Comment: Surely this information can be found in the operator's manual(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [list of specifications for the TS-480SAT](https://www.kenwood.com/i/products/info/amateur/ts_480/) giving the matching range as 16.7 Ω – 150 Ω.  Another [list of specifications for the TS-870SAT](https://www.universal-radio.com/catalog/hamhf/0870spec.html) says that model's matching range is 20 Ω – 150 Ω.  Both ranges roughly correspond to a 3:1 SWR, which is typical for antenna tuners built into transceivers.  External antenna tuners generally offer more tuning range than built-in tuners, so you might consider adding an external antenna tuner.